# mysql query to perform multiple inner joins on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I need to perform multiple joins on the same table. Below is my query.
When I execute following query , it gives me duplicate record for a single column.
Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT *,CONCAT(phno, ' ', vnumber) AS source,CONCAT(phno, ' ', vnumber) AS destination FROM gcm_users as gu
                                                INNER JOIN message_Log as ml1 ON gu.imei= ml1.Source_ID 
                                                INNER JOIN message_Log as ml2 ON gu.imei= ml2.Destination_ID
                                                WHERE  gu.id={$_SESSION['uid']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace 2 joins with one

```
INNER JOIN message_Log as ml1 ON gu.imei= ml1.Source_ID 
        OR gu.imei= ml2.Destination_ID
```

Comment: @JAY Then you'd be stepping in to the realm of the quantum reality